# Using query rewriting feature of declarative authorisation with sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, declarative-authorization, sorcery

I'm trying to use declarative authorisation at the model level using the query rewriting feature to filter down html select options something like this:

Model:

```
class TreatmentClinic < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.filtered_by_user_context
        with_permissions_to(:read)
    end
end
```

View(the new action):

```
<%= form_for(@something) do |f| %>

      <%= f.select :id, TreatmentClinic.filtered_by_user_context.collect {|t| [ t.name, t.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'Please select'} %>

      <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

authorization_roles.rb:

```
role :some_role do
    has_permission_on :treatment_clinics do
        to :read
        if_attribute :id => '1'
    end
end
```

I'm using sorcery and have it working nicely with declarative authorisation; declarative authorisation permissions are working fine at the controller and view levels, but the above select is throwing this error:

```
 No matching rules found for [:read] for #<Authorization::AnonymousUser:0x007fd257c00090 @role_symbols=[:guest]> (roles [:guest], privileges [:read, :manage], context :treatment_clinics).
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase it helps anyone in the future, I found the answer. In order for declarative authorisation security to work at the model level we need to add this to the application_controller.

```
  before_filter :set_current_user
  protected
  def set_current_user
    Authorization.current_user = current_user
  end
```